# Why do we need created_at in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Why do we when the `created_at` field when the `timestamp` can be found in the first 4 bytes of the `ObjectId`

```
ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4").getTimestamp()
```

Taken from [MongoDB Docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_objectid.htm)

Comment: We don't need it. But real date field makes it easier to actually retrieve/manipulate the timestamp (no need to transform it), but - especially, I think - it's much easier to filter by it when querying for documents.

Comment: If you'd made that an answer I'd definitely accept it.

Comment: It is good to note as well that in query operators for the timestamp within _id are still non-existent and not all drivers provide a decent helper to create time based _ids

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several cases where it makes sense to do so:

1. When you need better precision - `ObjectId.getTimestamp()` is precise up to seconds, while `Date` fields store milliseconds. Compare this in `mongo` shell: `new Date()` yields `ISODate("2016-01-03T21:21:38.032Z")`, while `ObjectId().getTimestamp()` yields `ISODate("2016-01-03T21:21:50Z")`.
2. When you are not using `ObjectId` at all - it is often taken as a given that `_id` field *should* be populated with `ObjectId`, while in fact `ObjectId` is only a default used by most of the drivers and [MongoDB itself doesn't impose it](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/document/#the-id-field) - on the contrary, it is encouraged to use any "natural" unique ID if it exists for the documents. In this case though you will have to store "creation timestamp" yourself if you need it.
3. Usability - if you rely on the presence of this field and the data in it, it might be better, at least from design standpoint, to be explicit about it. This is more a matter of taste though. However, as noted in comments, if you also want to filter or sort by "creation timestamp" - it will be easier to do having a dedicated field for it and using query operators like `$gt`, for example, directly on it.

Answer (score 6):

As you said, like it states clearly in the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_objectid.htm):

> Since the _id ObjectId by default stores the 4 byte timestamp, in most cases you **do not need** to store the creation time of any document.

And you may use `ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4").getTimestamp()` in order to get the creation date in ISO date format.

It is also a matter of convenience to the costumer (us) to have a service like that, as it makes our attempt of getting the creating date and performing actions on it much more intuitive and easy.

Comment: But be aware that some frameworks generate a ObjectId differently. Ex: Meteor states "ObjectID values created by Meteor will not have meaningful answers to their getTimestamp method, since Meteor currently constructs them fully randomly." http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-ObjectID